# How to select value of input onClick?

Tags: javascript

I have a `<input type="text">` and if user clicks inside it I want to make the content (value) of that box selected. How would I do that?

Comment: The question is quite broad, I assume you know to use javascript, maybe try and ask about the specifics

Comment: a hint: http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_using.asp

Comment: In IE its not working properly.. If you already have some value inside input box or any placeholder it is not working.. Can you tell me what to do ?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
<input type="text" onclick="select()"/>
```

Comment: In IE its not working properly.. If you already have some value inside input box or any placeholder it is not working.. Can you tell me what to do ?

Comment: And it's possible to unselect it? My idea is `select(); document.execCommand('copy'); unselect();`

Comment: how to select() if the onClick event is on another element , let's say an <i> tag then how to use select() to copy the value or the placeholder in the <input> tag, PS the 2 elements are in the same <div> tag parent , but the <i> tag , not a child of <input> tag

Answer (score 4):

Try `select` method:

```
document.getElementById("myinput").onclick = function() {
    this.select();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code inside a javaScript method,  and call the method onClick event of the textbox...

```
function calledOnClick(){

    document.getElementById('test').select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following `jQuery` code which automatically call on page load

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function() {
            this.select();
        });
    });
    $("#return_date").focus();
});
</script>
```